# Define calculated item in Zabbix for LXC discovery of Proxmox to compute % of RAM used

Tags: monitoring, zabbix

I am using Zabbix (6.4.10) with Proxmox plugin to monitor a proxmox server (and LXC containers).
In the discovery rule for LXC containers, there are two item prototypes regarding RAM :

- `proxmox.lxc.maxmem[{#LXC.ID}]` : memory total (in bytes)
- `proxmox.lxc.mem[{#LXC.ID}]` : memory usage (in bytes)

What I want to achieve is to define a calculated item prototype to have the percentage of used RAM (which I want to show in a Grafana dashboard).

I've tried to use this formula :
`last(//proxmox.lxc.mem[{#LXC.ID}])/last(//proxmox.lxc.memtotal[{#LXC.ID}])`
but I got this error message when I test it :
`Cannot evaluate function: item "/proxmox/proxmox.lxc.mem[{#LXC.ID}]" does not exist at "last(//proxmox.lxc.mem[{#LXC.ID}])/last(//proxmox.lxc.memtotal[{#LXC.ID}])".`

and I dont understand why.
The documentation shows some examples of caculated items, but not within discovery rules. Maybe my syntax is bad but I didnt found a relevant example to help me.

Items prototypes defined in Proxmox LXC discovery :

[image: Items prototypes defined in Proxmox LXC discovery]

My attempt to define a calculated item :

[image: My attempt to define a calculated item]

Comment: Calculated RAM usage in `%` should be like : `100*last(/your_host_name/proxmox.lxc.mem[{#LXC.ID}])/last(/your_host_name/proxmox.lxc.memtotal[{#LXC.ID}])` - Your formula seems good. It is maybe an issue with item prototype.

Comment: Did you try like that : `100*last(/Proxmox VE by HTTP/proxmox.lxc.mem[{#LXC.ID}])/last(/Proxmox VE by HTTP/proxmox.lxc.maxmem[{#LXC.ID}])` ? - It appears that you created another discovery template called "LXC discovery".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*My answer assumes you are using [this](https://git.zabbix.com/projects/ZBX/repos/zabbix/browse/templates/app/proxmox/template_app_proxmox.yaml) template.*

**First point :** item `proxmox.lxc.memtotal[{#LXC.ID}]` does not exist.

This template is pretty fine for `ProxMox VE` hosts monitoring. However, this template is quite "complex" and is separated into several sub-parts / hosts.

With screenshots you provided, it appears that you are in the `LXC discovery` host. However, both items `proxmox.lxc.mem[{#LXC.ID}]` and `proxmox.lxc.maxmem[{#LXC.ID}]` **belongs to** `Proxmox VE by HTTP` host. You can check with :

```
item:   
  host: 'Proxmox VE by HTTP'   
  key: 'proxmox.lxc.mem[{#LXC.ID}]'

[...]

item:   
  host: 'Proxmox VE by HTTP'   
  key: 'proxmox.lxc.maxmem[{#LXC.ID}]'
```

By doing this :

```
last(//proxmox.lxc.mem[{#LXC.ID}])/last(//proxmox.lxc.memtotal[{#LXC.ID}])
```

Zabbix engine **assumes** the items are in the `LXC discovery` host and do not find them.

It translates like :

```
last(/LXC discovery/proxmox.lxc.mem[{#LXC.ID}])/last(/LXC discovery/proxmox.lxc.memtotal[{#LXC.ID}])
```

It can't work like that.

#### Conclusion

You need to do something like :

```
100*last(/Proxmox VE by HTTP/proxmox.lxc.mem[{#LXC.ID}])/last(/Proxmox VE by HTTP/proxmox.lxc.maxmem[{#LXC.ID}])
```

I added `100*` at the beginning as it is a percentage.